# Send date by Radio-check to other page

Tags: php

i have form to send data to other page like:

```
<input name="ShowBuy" id="ShowBuy" type="radio" value="1" checked = "checked"> Show Buy
<input name="ShowBuy" id="ShowBuy" type="radio" value="0"> Hide Buy <br>
<input name="ShowSale" id="ShowSale" type="radio" value="1" checked = "checked"> Show Sale
<input name="ShowSale" id="ShowSale" type="radio" value="0"> Hide Sale<br>
```

when i checked Hide Buy and print the result, it show value "1" !!! why, it must show me value "0" .
there are code to send :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  $(function(){
           $('#Normal').click(function(){
               sessionStorage.ShowSale = $("#ShowSale").val();
               sessionStorage.ShowBuy = $("#ShowBuy").val();
              window.open('Print.php', '_blank')  
           }); 
       });   
</script>
```

where problem here.

Comment: can you show us the code you're using to process the data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the jquery code is that you are using an ID selector, an ID is supposed to be the unique identifier for one element, jquery will match the first element with that id and return the value

Here's one solution:

```
<input name="ShowBuy" class="ShowBuy" type="radio" value="1" checked = "checked"> Show Buy
<input name="ShowBuy" class="ShowBuy" type="radio" value="0"> Hide Buy <br>
<input name="ShowSale" class="ShowSale" type="radio" value="1" checked = "checked"> Show Sale
<input name="ShowSale" class="ShowSale" type="radio" value="0"> Hide Sale<br>
```

Above I have substitued the `id` attribute for `class`

You then need to alter your jquery:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  $(function(){
           $('#Normal').click(function(){
               sessionStorage.ShowSale = $("input.ShowSale:checked").val();
               sessionStorage.ShowBuy = $("input.ShowBuy:checked").val();
              window.open('Print.php', '_blank')  
           }); 
       });   
</script>
```

This now selects an input with `class="ShowBuy"` and is checked and gets the value